# php script that print all src of any image in a splider site

Tags: php, memory-management

I'm using SimpleHTMLDOM to retrive all uri of all images of a site, but during the execution i'm getting a memory usage error, how to solve?

```
$count = 0;
$last = 1721;
include('simple_html_dom.php');

while ( $count <= $last) { 

$html = file_get_html('http://myuri/?from='.$count);

// find all image inside post div
    foreach($html->find('div.itemPost img') as $e) {

        echo $e->src . '<br>';

    }

}
```

this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in /home/peppo1616/public_html/script/simple_html_dom.php on line 1189
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Allowed+memory+size+of+134217728

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 1):

Call the destructor after looping through img tags and assign `null` to `$html` to clear some memory.

```
while ( $count <= $last) { 
    $html = file_get_html('http://myuri/?from='.$count);

    // find all image inside post div
    foreach($html->find('div.itemPost img') as $e) {
        echo $e->src . '<br>';
    }

    $html->clear();
    $html = null;
}
```

On a side note, I don't see any incrementation of `$count`, you may end with infinite loop.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaafffffffffffffffffffffff